# Programar atualizações automáticas no R

Tags: r

Eu tenho um algoritmo no projetado em R que recuperados dados de uma banco de dados, faz alguns cálculos estatísticos e produz uma dashboard com kpis e gráficos gerados desses cálculos. Mas, todas vez que quero atualizar as informações, tenho que executar a função para que os cálculos sejam refeitos. Existe alguma forma de eu programar uma atualização automática desses cálculos no R assim que abro o código e enquanto eu o deixo aberto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, existe. Em um emprego passado meu, construímos um dash em shiny que basicamente era um `while (true)` e `Sys.sleep(5)` que ficava atualizando os dados do dashboard.

Certamente seria necessário refatorar o código para essa nova estrutura.

Todavia, não sei se faria assim hoje. Eu provavelmente faria a extração e atualização de uma base de dados local com um script dedicado somente à isso (provavelmente em `python`, mas poderia ser em `R` mesmo) e eu o executaria periodicamente com um `cron` job se o seu O.S. for *nix ou com o `Task Scheduler` no Windows.

Se o processamento de dados for muito complexo, com várias dependências e decisões no processo, faria uma aplicação com `Make` (que tem um package para facilitar na linguagem `R`) ou teria um servidor/processo local com `Airflow` ou `Luigi` que tomaria conta só da extração e processamento dos dados, e a aplicação do Dash apenas conectaria com a fonte de dados, atualizando a cada X tempo ou com um botão de atualizar, deixando à cargo do usuário.