# Monitoramento com o R

Tags: r, loop, monitoramento

tenho um script de monitoramento e gostaria de executa ele a cada cinco minutos, existe alguma função que faça isso?

por exemplo:

```
função (meu_script, repetir= 5 minutos)
```

tentei algumas funções com `Sys.time()` e `proc.time()` , mas não consegui nada de proveitoso.

Comment: Seguem alguns links que podem te ajudar. [link1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220881/programar-atualiza%C3%A7%C3%B5es-autom%C3%A1ticas-no-r/221362#221362), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451467/get-online-data-every-hour-in-r), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069989/scheduling-r-functions-after-every-particular-time-interval?lq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao invés de inserir o tempo de repetição dentro de sua função, tente utilizá-lo com a função `repeat`. Exemplo com intervalo de 5 segundos:

```
repeat{
  função()
  Sys.sleep(5)
}
```